# Each image in image stack has an opacity percentage as a fraction of total images

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack, opacity

I'm building my own modal (lightbox, pop up) for an image gallery — similar I guess to Fancybox, for example.

I have a page of images, each image represents a specific work or project — if you click on an image a modal window would pop up with the ability to cycle through a set of images related to that work. Some images might have twelve images in its set... some only one.

What I'm doing is stacking the images on top of each other (a crude example but similar to this: http://goo.gl/TmNPs) — and you have a close/remove button on each image as you close/remove each image in the stack until you get to the last then the whole modal closes.

What I'm trying to achieve is this sense of depth with the stack with opacity percentage. If there's twelve images in the stack, the front image has an opacity of 100% and each image after that has an opacity a fraction of 12. So, the last image would have an opacity of 100%/12, the second to last image would have an opacity of 100%/12*2, third to last 100%/12*3 and so forth. Then as each image is closed, the opacity changes to reflect this.

I'm looking for a bit of direction and guidance on how/if this could possibly be achieved — preferably using jQuery.

Many thanks,
R

Comment: Could you post a live example of your current attempt so far?

Comment: If these images are in a stack and the front image has 100% opacity, then surely it doesn't matter what opacity the underlying images have - the front image will mask them. Or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: It's just a feature, really. Something visual to play with.